# Code First Migration Creating an addition attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create a table using code first EF with these attributes :

```
public class HistoryRead
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Book_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string User_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

and I added the needed relations to both tables :

```
public partial class AspNetUser
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public AspNetUser()
    {

        HistoryReads = new HashSet<HistoryRead>();

    }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HistoryRead> HistoryReads { get; set; }

}
```

and :

```
 public partial class Book
{
    public Book()
    {

        HistoryReads = new HashSet<HistoryRead>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Book_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="User Name")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string User_ID { get; set; }



    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }



    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title Name")]
    [StringLength(70,MinimumLength =3)]
    public string Book_name { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<HistoryRead> HistoryReads { get; set; }

}
```

and then I runs the migration and got this result !

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.HistoryReads",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Book_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    User_Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    AspNetUser_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.AspNetUser_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Book", t => t.Book_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Book_Id)
            .Index(t => t.AspNetUser_Id);

    }
```

as you seen in migration generated code I got an extra attribute called "AspNetUser_Id" and I don't need that , even when I tried to remove it and continue my work I got an exception from db side .. so how to solve this problem and thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what I should expect in the migration. You have a virtual of `AspNetUser` inside your HistoryRead and EF creates an AspNetUser_Id to match it to your user. It doesn't know that you want to use User_Id as key. This is the reason the exception is thrown.

The reason it does work at book is because it uses the convention of _Id and it knows it is the foreign key of the book virtual.

I would suggest you remove the User_Id and Book_Id from your model. EF will take care of the relationship and the foreignkeys it needs. This way the model will be cleaner and you can access it through the virtual.

As asked, the example of how to add a new relation to an object.

```
var historyObject = dbContext.Set<HistoryRead>().GetById(1);
var bookObject = dbContext.Set<Book>().GetByTitle("Example");
historyObject.Book = bookObject;
dbContext.Set<HistoryRead>().Update(historyObject);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Already I have another table created before 1 week ago and holding same attribute and relation but when I used migration it created it without any extra attribute !

Comment: Hmm that is strange. I'll do some research and come back to it.

Comment: If I want to follow your solution and remove the user_id and book_id ... how I can add new data to the table ? because if I will use the usually way it will not recognition the attributes :
HistoryRead ReadH = new HistoryRead()
                    {
                        Book_Id = result.Book_id,
                        User_Id = x.ToString()
                    };

Comment: You add them as an object to the historyRead object (using the virtual) and then save the history read object.

Comment: I don't know how you use your dbContext, but will give an example of how I normally do it. Hopefully you can use it.